# In nested loops, on seeing a pattern how can we determine how many loops will print it?

Tags: java, loops

```
12345
2345
345
45
5
```

On seeing above code it can be determined that 2 loops will print it

```
123456789
912345678
891234567
789123456
678912345
567891234
456789123
345678912
234567891
```

How many loops will print it how can we determine it

Comment: what do you by mean how many loop ? How does 2 loop print above code ?

Comment: public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
   int i,j;
   for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
   {
       for(j=i;j<=5;j++)
       System.out.print(j);
   }
   System.out.println();
        }
    }
}  will these code not print the first loop. Check it and how many means that can we determine the no. of loops on seeing the pattern for printing it

Answer (score 1):

You can print both the patterns using just one for loop :

```
        String pattern = "12345";
        int length = pattern.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            System.out.println(pattern);
            //remove the first char after every iteration
            pattern = pattern.substring(1);
        }
        System.out.println();
        pattern = "123456789";
        length = pattern.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            System.out.println(pattern);
            String lastchar = pattern.substring(length-1);
            String otherchars = pattern.substring(0, length-1);
            //append last char to front after every iteration
            pattern = lastchar.concat(otherchars);
        }
```

The output :

```
12345
2345
345
45
5

123456789
912345678
891234567
789123456
678912345
567891234
456789123
345678912
234567891
```